# How to style an image with text block?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create a style I can reuse that will create the following layout.
Place an image and float it left, then have text with or without paragraph tags that are positioned to the right of said image.  The text will be aligned to the top of the image on the left.

I can achieve everything except the text isn't positioned at the top.  Here is what I have so far, the text being centered and not top aligned.

```
<div style="overflow:auto">
<div style="float:left">
    <a href="Images/img.jpg"><img src="Images/img.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div>
    <p>this is some text that is getting centered along the img height</p>
    <p>Some more text... </p>
</div>
</div>
```

example of what this does.  I need the 3 paragraphs aligned to top of image and 4th how it is already.
[example http://www.spokanewastewater.org/Images/untitled.jpg](http://www.spokanewastewater.org/Images/untitled.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do 2 things for this.

On your first paragraph tag, add the styles below. This will remove the spacing that is caused by the first paragraph tag.

```
<p style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0"></p>
```

And on the image, the style below. Sometimes if you don't set a vertical align the image will be off a little. But I would need to see a JSFiddle to see how yours is rendering.

```
<img style="vertical-align:top">
```

Also, I should add that this should be done with an external CSS sheet and not inline, if possible.

Comment: Yes it was just for development, I'm going to move it into my css once I had it working, which thanks to you it is!!  I will mark as answer when I can.  Thank you again!

Comment: Great no problem. I just updated the answer too with some explanations.

Comment: Ah that's what the extra space in the top was, the p tag causing space ABOVE and below... duh!  I thought it had something to do with the img taking up that space.